# Removing disabled="disabled" attribute for a checkbox in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

## How would I go about removing the disabled="disabled" attribute for a CheckBox inside a GridView...

.ascx file

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHidden" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpePopUp" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblHidden" PopupControlID="divPopUp" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<div id="divPopUp" style="background: #eee;">
    <div id="Header" class="header" style="padding:8px;"><h2>Please select the items that are being excluded from the order</h2></div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server" style="padding:8px;font-size: 15px !important;"></asp:Panel>

    <%-- I want my DataTable/GridView right here --%>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CellPadding="2" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" runat="server">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" BorderColor="#cccccc" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="gridRowStyle" BorderColor="#cccccc" BackColor="#eeeeee" />
            <Columns>
            </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div style="height: 24px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 7px;"><b>No Line Items Found For This Order!</b></div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>

    <div id="buttons" style="display:inline-block; padding:8px;">
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonPartial" runat="server" Text="Submit" BorderStyle="Solid" ToolTip="Submit" OnClick="ButtonPartial_Click" style="padding:2px;"/>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancelPartial" runat="server" Text="Cancel" BorderStyle="Solid" ToolTip="Cancel" OnClick="ButtonCancelPartial_Click" style="padding:2px;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

c# code to generate the CheckBox in the GridView

```
    protected void LineItemsModalTable(string orderNumber)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var selectColumn = new DataColumn("Excluding Selected", typeof(bool))
        {
            DefaultValue = true
        };
        dt.Columns.Add(selectColumn); //this will show checkboxes
        string sql = String.Format(@"sql stuff", orderNumber);

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringStuff"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //fill the datatable with the contents from the database
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            //bind the datasource to the gridview
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            //trying to remove the attribuyte of disabled.
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                //var i = 0;
                //var uniqueID = row.Cells[0].ID;
                //CheckBox chkRow = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl(uniqueID) as CheckBox;
                //chkRow.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
                //i++;
                row.Cells[0].Attributes.Remove("disabled");
            }
        }
```

Output:

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzGVr.png)
[Inspect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1tiZ.png)

Basically when you save, it does some stuff and then brings you to the LineItemsModalTable function. I think this is the code that is breaking it but I have not been able to find anything that has helped me so far...

```
var selectColumn = new DataColumn("Excluding Selected", typeof(bool))
{
     DefaultValue = true
};
dt.Columns.Add(selectColumn); //this will show checkboxes
```

I also tried to loop through the GridView rows and remove the attribute but it doesn't allow me because it's saying it's a DisabledCssClass. I want to be able to do this in the server side code, and I want to be able to click the check boxes, but right now they are disabled. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does this post help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884681/boolean-datacolumn-state-not-editable ? You should use a template field.

Comment: @RivoR. I am fairly new .net so you're saying to dynamically add template fields with checkboxes in instead of just adding a column full of checkboxes?

Comment: Yes. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592785/add-columns-dynamically-to-grid-view-with-itemtemplate and this too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

Comment: @RivoR. this worked perfectly. I appreciate you brotha!